# How to print default HTTP GET/POST REQUEST/RESPONSE Headers and add new headers in request using net/http in Ruby on console

Tags: ruby, http, get

I want to print GET/POST http headers like following on Console using net/http.

```
GET /en HTTP/1.1
Host: www.html5rocks.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101          Firefox/10.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 09:10:23 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 8940
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print headers by this way:

```
uri = URI('http://www.html5rocks.com/en')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }
  response = http.request request
  response.header.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }
end
```

Comment: I want to print request headers also , the above one worked fine for ma thanks for that but need to print request headers also.

Comment: But it still shows only accept = */* for request header, how to print other request header like User-Agent, Accept-Encoding and Origin etc.

Comment: It up to you which request headers you sent. You can add request headers by using for example add_field method. Please read the documentation http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html